# Laravel redirect if authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Why doesn't my redirect work? I am using Laravel's native authorrization, and have changed both `LoginController.php` and `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` redirect path to admin, but no luck.

Here are my routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin_temp');
    });

    Route::resource('users', 'WPUserController');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to redirect user after login, you can change `$redirectTo` variable in `Auth\AuthController.php`:

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

If you want to redirect all authenticated users to some URL - this is an awful idea, because your app will not work (users will be redirected to the same URL with every reuqest). Maybe you want to redirect non authenticated users to login page or something?

Also, you could override `handleUserWasAuthenticated()` in `Auth\AuthController.php` method (Laravel 5.2) or `sendLoginResponse()` in `Auth\LoginController.php` method (Laravel 5.3). Copy-paste it and change `return` clause to something like this:

```
return redirect()->route('my.route');
```

Comment: I wanted to redirect after login...so if user credentials are right, take him to '/admin'. I have changed the $redirectTo to '/admin' but it takes me to '/'

Comment: Yep, it's buggy. Documentation says to change `$redirectTo`. You can try to add this variable: `protected $redirectPath = '/admin';`

Comment: Damn, no, still the same...guess I'll have to come up with some out-of-the-box solution

Comment: It works for me. Anyway, if you'll solve this please tell me how did you do that.

Comment: Btw, you could try to override `handleUserWasAuthenticated()` method (`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`) in your `AuthController.php`. It definetely should work.

Comment: I have found changing methods in vendor folder a bad practice because when I upload the project on GitHub, vendor folder is ignored...and then it crashes when I pull it on some other place

Comment: I didn't say to change anything in vendor directory, of course you don't want to do this. Override it in `AuthController` which is in `app\Controllers\Auth` directory.

Comment: AuthenticatesUsers.php is in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate... :) As for AuthController.php, new Laravel version doesn't have it :)

Comment: If you're using 5.3, override `sendLoginResponse()` method in `Auth\LoginController.php`

Comment: Override to what? Does some documentation exist about it?

Comment: Copy-paste original method to `LoginController.php` and change `return ...` clause to something like `return redirect()->route('my.route');`

Comment: That actually works! Thanks, update answer and I'll accept it. Btw, there are no bad outcomes with this?